# Adding a Google Calendar to a view in Xcode

Tags: xcode, ios5

I'm learning iOS programming and I'm at a very basic level.
I hope somebody can help me with a test project I'm trying to do.

In a view of my app I'd like to show a Google Calendar.
The source calendar will always be the same and events will be added via web site, so there's no need for the user to modify or add anything.
The view should just show a list (tableview?) of events fetched from google and touching each event should push another view with the event's details.

I've tried to see the documents for the Google's API, but, honestly, I'm not able to implement it without help.